# Powershell [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.controls") is not loading

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, .net-assembly

I'm working with Powershell to manipulate WPF datagrid. 
I'm trying to add a DataGridComboBoxColumn and I have to load this assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.controls") | Out-Null

However, it keeps giving me an error

I'm not sure if I'm loading this assembly the wrong way. 
can you please assist?

Thank you

Comment: Whats the Error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to load a namespace when you should instead be trying to load the assembly containing the namespace.

`System.Windows.Controls` is namespace within `PresentationFramewkork.dll`

Can you try loading PresentationFramework instead?

```
PS> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("PresentationFramework")

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0....

PS> $object = [System.Windows.Controls.Control]

PS> $object.GetMembers()

Name                       : get_BorderBrush
DeclaringType              : System.Windows.Controls.Control
ReflectedType              : System.Windows.Controls.Control
MemberType                 : Method
MetadataToken              : 100680700
Module                     : PresentationFramework.dll
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Wells its already loaded.

Try running this.

```
$ExportedTypes = [appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | select ExportedTypes
Foreach($ExportedType in $ExportedTypes){
    $ExportedType.ExportedTypes | ?{$_.FullName -like "system.windows.controls*"} | select FullName, Module
}
```

If you get any results it is already loaded.

The Assembly you are loading is actually part of PresentationFramework.dll